# Geom_text position with ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I have a large amount of graphs using ggplot2. When using `ggplotly`, my `geom_text` does not obey the `ggplot()` position. See chart below:

```
 library(data.table)
 library(tidyverse)
 url <- "https://raw.githack.com/fsbmat-ufv/stackExchange/main/df.csv"
 test <- fread(url)

 plot <- ggplot(test,
                aes(reorder(factor(UF), desc(Value)),
                    y = Value,
                    fill = UF,
                    text = paste("UF: ",UF,
                                 "<br>",
                                 "Value: ",paste0("R$",formatC(1000000000*Value, digits = 2, big.mark=',', format = 'f'))))) +
   geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
   geom_text(aes(label=Value),
             position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
             vjust = -0.5,
             size = 3) +
   xlab("Federal Unit") +
   ylab("Amount Received") +
   theme_light()
 plotly::ggplotly(plot, tooltip = "text")%>%
   plotly::layout(showlegend = FALSE)
```

[image: insert image description here]

I tried several solutions, one of them was to use the `style` function of `plotly` with the `textposition=’top’` option. However, my `tooltip` appears over the chart bars and I can't resolve it.

```
 plotly::ggplotly(plot, tooltip = "text")%>%
   plotly::style(textposition = "top") %>%
   plotly::layout(showlegend = FALSE)
```

[image: insert image description here]

The `textposition` option affects `geom_text` as well as `tooltip`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to manually nudge the `y` position for the labels instead of using `vjust`:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

url <- "https://raw.githack.com/fsbmat-ufv/stackExchange/main/df.csv"
test <- fread(url)

plot <- ggplot(
  test,
  aes(reorder(factor(UF), desc(Valor)),
    y = Valor,
    fill = UF,
    text = paste(
      "UF: ", UF,
      "<br>",
      "Value: ", paste0("R$", formatC(1000000000 * Valor, digits = 2, big.mark = ",", format = "f"))
    )
  )
) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Valor, y = Valor + .1),
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
    vjust = .5,
    size = 3
  ) +
  xlab("Federal Unit") +
  ylab("Amount Received") +
  theme_light()

plot
```

[image]

```
plotly::ggplotly(plot, tooltip = "text") %>%
  plotly::layout(showlegend = FALSE)
```

[image]